# Unable to set bluetooth device as trusted using bluez-tools on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian, bluez

I'm wanting to set my ipod as a trusted bluetooth device on my raspberry pi running raspian via command line using bluez-tools.

On Ubuntu I run:

```
bt-device --set 28:37:37:B5:1A:B5 Trusted 1
```

The output is:

```
Trusted: 0 -> 1
```

On my Raspberry pi the same bt-device commend is entered the following is output:

```
bt-device: bluez service is not found
Did you forget to run bluetoothd?
```

I have run the command

```
bluetoothd
```

on my Raspberry Pi, it seems to be running.

The Raspberry is running bluez Version: 4.99-2, and bluez-tools Version: 0.1.38+git662e-3

Thanks!

Comment: send some dbus command for bluetoothd to check if bluetoothd is running or not? This command will help u to list down the bt adapters   "dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.bluez "/" org.bluez.Manager.ListAdapters"

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
bluez-test-device trusted xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx yes
bluez-test-input connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx yes
```